# PHP preg_match result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, extract, email-address

This PHP function working just fine:

```
if (preg_match ("/<(\S+@\S+\w)>.*\n?.*55[0-9]/i",$body,$match)) {
echo "found!";
}
```

in

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

xxx@hotmail.com
SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<xxx@hotmail.com>:
host mx3.hotmail.com [65.54.188.72]: 550 Requested action not taken:
mailbox unavailable
```

But if I use the same php function in this case:

```
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its 
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

xxx@yahoo.com
SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
host d.mx.mail.yahoo.com [209.191.88.254]: 554 delivery error:
dd This user doesn't have a yahoo.com account (xxxd@yahoo.com) [0] -  mta1010.mail.mud.yahoo.com
```

The `preg_match` function does not give any results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically looking for a email addressing enclosed in `<` and `>`.

Your first input has it but the second input does not: It has no email id in `<  >` hence you don't get a match.

Edit: (after your comment):

Looking at the 2 samples given by you the email id appears between the string `failed:` and the error code starting with `55`. You can make use of the preg_match for this as:

```
if(preg_match('/failed:.*?(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b).*55[\d]/is',$str,$m)) {
       echo "Bounced email ".$m[1]."\n";
}
```

[**Ideone link**](http://www.ideone.com/D3tUL)

Comment: So I have to remove "<" from the function?

Comment: @Sergio: It's not very clear what you are looking for. The text given by you are failed messaged delivery messages. Are you looking for `xxx@hotmail.com` and `xxx@yahoo.com` ? If yes, you can look for the email pattern that follows the text `failed:`.

Comment: This is the part of the script aimed to check bounced Emails using the text (errors) in bounced messages. What I need is the email address of the message that was sent and bounce back. In these cases xxx@hotmail.com and xxx@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

By default, preg_match doesn't support parsing of multiline string (String containing \n), so you gotta pass in extra parameter to match the whole string, which is m (multiline).

try

```
if (preg_match ("/<(\S+@\S+\w)>.*\n?.*55[0-9]/im",$body,$match)) {
echo "found!";
}
```

Comment: Ok, can you explicitly tell us what you are trying to match?